# Concurrency in Elm

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, concurrency, elm

I have a really computationally expensive code that I need to run in my 'update' function.

When it runs, my whole app blocks until it finishes.

Is there any way to run this code asynchronously to prevent the blocking? (while not using ports and staying in elm)

Comment: using something like: https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-web-workers ?

Comment: It seems kind of nasty at the moment I would rather find another way if I could. You cannot pass the more complex types of elm only strings

Answer (score 2):

Elm tasks do not support pre-emptive multi-tasking.

With `Process.spawn`, you can construct tasks which will context-switch when used as arguments to `Task.andThen`.

However, for those, you have to work within the constraint that the resulting task has type `Task x Process.Id`, which means there is no easy way to communicate the result of your task back to the main app.

See [the documentation](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.5/Process#Id) for `Process.Id`.

Comment: I actually tried using Process.Id a couple days ago, but seemed to yield the same blocking effect :(

Comment: Well, it's pretty much useless at the moment, and it still blocks... It appears like it can't be done in this version

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run it as a Task. Tasks can be preemptively be stopped to execute other parts of your application, although I'm unsure how they will work in the case of some using the entirety of the CPU capacity:

```
DoHeavyStuff a b ->
    let
        task param1 param2 =
            Task.succeed 1
            `Task.andThen` (\_ -> Task.succeed <| expensive param1 param2)
    in
    (model, Task.perform NoOp FinishedWork (task a b))

FinishedWork result ->
    ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work as the expensive operation is evaluated before the task is run because elm is a strict language. The entire thing still blocks :(

Comment: Maybe try with an andThen trick? `Task.suceed 1 andThen \_ -> expensive`

Comment: The right side of `andThen` expects a function that returns a Task and not a function that returns the result :/ Seems like we cannot get out of it this way

Comment: Sorry, I did not add the right code... let me put it in the answer itself... Let me know if it works

Comment: You're right... I tried it myself and does not seem to work as I expected